# no he podido realizar copias de seguridad en cron de cpanel por la ruta de mysqldump

Tags: mysql, cpanel

```
 "dump" => [
                'dump_binary_path' =>'C:\xampp\mysql\bin', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
           'use_single_transaction',
           'timeout' => 60 * 5,
```

En el código local le coloco **C:\xampp\mysql\bin** y si me hace el respaldo pero en el servidor no me lo hace, y me envía el correo como si lo hubiera realizado

Answer (score 0):

En cPanel **mysqldump** está en:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump
```

Por lo tanto tu código deberia quedar así:

```
"dump" => [
                'dump_binary_path' =>'/usr/bin/', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
           'use_single_transaction',
           'timeout' => 60 * 5,
```

Ya nos comentas si funciona ahora.